# Quick Question on integrating with dummy variables

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I want to show, by integrating twice, that any solution to (1) is a solution to (2) detailed below:
$$ y''=f(y) \qquad \qquad y(0)=0 \qquad y'(0)=1 \qquad(1)$$
$$ y(x)= x+ \int_0^x{(x-s)f(y(s)})ds \qquad (2)$$

First I got: 
$$ [y'(x)]_0^x = \int_0^x{f(t)}dt $$
so $$ y'(x) =1 + \int_0^x{f(t)}dt $$

Then I put:
$$ y(x) = x + \int_0^x{\int_0^s{f(t)}dt} ds $$
But I can't make the final step! Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have $f(y(t))$ in the integrals, so from your work we have that $$ y(x) = x + \int_0^x\int_0^s f(y(t)) \, dt \, ds.$$ For simplicity, set $F(s) = \int_0^s f(y(t)) \, dt$. Note that $F'(s) = f(y(s)).$ Then we can apply integration by parts to the integral $\int_0^x\int_0^s f(y(t)) \, dt\, ds = \int_0^x F(s)\, ds$ to get that
\begin{align*}
\int_0^x 1\cdot F(s) \, ds &= sF(s)|^x_0 - \int_0^x s F'(s)\, ds \\
&=xF(x) -\int_0^xsf(y(s)) \, ds \\
&= x\int_0^xf(y(s))\, d s-\int_0^xsf(y(s)) \, ds \\
&= \int_0^x(x-s)f(y(s))\, ds.
\end{align*}
Thus we have that
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= x + \int_0^x\int_0^s f(y(t)) \, dt \, ds \\
&= x  + \int_0^x(x-s)f(y(s))\, ds
\end{align*}
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Then you use integration by parts. Call $F(x)=\int_0^xf(y(t))\,dt$. Then
$$
y(x)=x+\int_0^xF(s)\,ds=x-[(x-s)F(s)]_0^x+\int_0^x(x-s)F'(s)\,ds\,.
$$
In general you get from the Taylor expansion with integral remainder term
$$
y(x)=y(0)+y'(0)x+\frac{y^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n+\int_0^x\frac{y^{(n+1)}(s)}{n!}\,.(x-s)^n\,ds
$$